# Windows color to single integer

Tags: c#, colors, drawing, system

I'm working with an API that only supports byte values for the RGB components of a color. I am trying to differentiate a variable amount of items, say between 8 and 12. I would like to assign each item a color. So if there are 10 items, I would divide the range into 10 and assign each item the corresponding color (think rainbow). It looked like `toArgb()` would work, but more reading indicated that is may use hexadecimal. I would obviously need to extract the RGB valued to send back to the API.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? do you need just an algorithm which will generate some given number of different colors?

Comment: what is your point is it classification by colors?

Comment: Are the colors supposed to have a gradient transition?

Comment: Yes, I would end up with an algorithm that would generate a given number of colors. But really I need to know format for color input that can be divided into equal parts.

Comment: On screen the user will be trying to organize items. The items are currently B&W, assigning colors will mate it easier.

Comment: Each item would be a solid color. But the items would as a whole would appear to transition through the spectrum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood you will have as input a color range and the number of items. Also, you would like that the generated colors would represent a color gradient.

Try this:

```
// set the edges of the color range
var firstColor = Color.Red;
var secondColor = Color.Green;

int rMin = firstColor.R;
int rMax = secondColor.R;
int bMin = firstColor.B;
int bMax = secondColor.B;
int gMin = firstColor.G;
int gMax = secondColor.G;

int size = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    var rAverage = rMin + (int)((rMax - rMin) * i / size);
    var gAverage = gMin + (int)((gMax - gMin) * i / size);
    var bAverage = bMin + (int)((bMax - bMin) * i / size);
    var currentColor = Color.FromArgb(rAverage, gAverage, bAverage);
    // TODO: use the currentColor
}
```